# Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers for Chip BCM4360 on Kali Linux

Tags: networking, kali-linux, broadcom

There are a fair amount of Kali Linux tutorials I have gone over in order to attempt to get the wireless drivers on my 15" retina 2013 macbook pro.

None of anything that I have done is working. Any help/guidance for install Kali Linux dual boot on mac and getting the wireless drivers to work?

Answer (score 0):

There is a link i have to download the b43 drivers needed with a readme... The reason they are not pre-installed is most likely because the native drivers are actually different, and are not meant to run on Mac broadcom chips :try it here - https://gregoryconrad.github.io/downloads/wifi_on_kali.zip